# what is class="centerPanel"

Tags: dojo, dijit.layout

I see many Dojo examples and tutorials passing the property "class": "centerPanel", but I can't find any documentation anywhere.

What is it? It seems to be passed to layouts, but what is it for? (I understand it's a CSS class, but where is it defined?)

[Here is an example from the dojo tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/dijit_layout/demo/appLayout.php)

The snippet that I am would like to understand is this:

```
    <div class="centerPanel"
         data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"
         data-dojo-props="region: 'center'">
        [...]
    </div>
```

Comment: No idea, but most browser tools will let you "trace styles" and see where a style originates.

Comment: @TimMedora I tried using chrome's debugger but it does not look like there is a CSS class named 'centerPanel'. Is this just a class name used as a marker? If so to what end?

Comment: Sometimes libraries use marker classes so that you can 1) detect their presence or 2) style them or 3) style their descendants. I've never used Dojo, so I can only guess in this case :)

Comment: perhaps you could post a reference to one of these examples?